# Why labels are mentioned three times in a single deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I've gone over the following docomentation page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

The example deployment yaml is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

We can see here three different times where the label `app: nginx` is mentioned.

Why do we need each of them? I had a hard time understanding it from the official documentation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The **first label** is for deployment itself, it gives label for that particular deployment. Lets say you want to delete that deployment then you run following command:

```
kubectl delete deployment -l app=nginx
```

This will delete the entire deployment.

The **second label** is `selector: matchLabels` which tells the resources(service etc) to match the pod according to label. So lets say if you want to create the service which has all the pods having labels of `app=nginx` then you provide following definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port:  80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

The above service will look for the matchLabels and bind pods which have label `app: nginx` assigned to them

The **third label** is `podTemplate` labels, the `template` is actually `podTemplate`. It describe the pod that it is launched. So lets say you have two replica deployment and k8s will launch 2 pods with the label specified in `template: metadata: labels`. This is subtle but important difference, so you can have the different labels for deployment and pods generated by that deployment.

Comment: I assume then that the second one is required and the other two are optional?

Comment: Where do we use the deployment label? (the first label)

Comment: The first label is added on the deployment object to select the deployment using labels. For example you have a group of deployment which you want to select from a single command. You can label all the deployments with one label and select from one command : `kubectl get deployment -l app=nginx`

Comment: Is there a use case for a Deployment definition where the labels listed in `.spec.selector.matchLabels` differ from the ones listed in the same Deployment's `.spec.template.metadata.labels` section?

Answer (score 8):

First label:

It is deployment label which is used to select deployment. You can use below command using first label:

```
kubectl get deployment -l app=nginx
```

Second Label:

It is not a label . It is label selector to select pod with labels nginx. It is used by ReplicaSet.

Third Label:

It is pod label to identify pods. It is used by ReplicaSet to maintain desired num of replica and for that label selector is used.
Also it is used to selects pod with below command:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=nginx
```

Answer (score 3):

As we know it, the labels are to identify the resources,

- First label identifies the Deployment itself
- Third one is falls under the Pod template section. So, this one is specific to the Pod.
- Second one i.e the matchLabels is used to tell Services, ReplicaSet and other resources to act on the resources on the specified label conditions.

While first and third ones are label assignment to Deployment and Pods respectively, the second one is matching condition expression rather than assignment.

Though all 3 have same labels in the real world examples, First one can be different than second and third ones. But, second and third one usually to be identical as the second is the conditional expression that acts upon third one.

Answer (score 2):

`.metadata.labels` is for labeling the `deployment` object itself, you don't necessarily need it, but like other answers said, it helps you organize objects.

`.spec.selector` tells the `deployment`(under the hood it is the `ReplicaSet` object) how to find the pods to manage. For your example, it will manage pods with label `app: nginx`.

But how do you tell the ReplicaSet controller to create pods with that label in the first place? You define that in the pod template, `.spec.template.metadata.labels`.

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**

1st label (`.metadata.labels`): the label for the `Deployments`

2nd label (`.spec.selector.matchLabels`): tell `ReplicaSets` what pods to govern.

3rd label (`.spec.template.metadata.labels`): the label for the `Pod` so that it can be found by the `ReplicaSets`.